# A scheme for swap space on a USB

Tags: linux, partitioning, lvm, swap, device-mapper

I have recently bought a USB flash drive that I am going to use solely for swap partitions. I understand that swap files on flash media are likely to use up the number of write cycles rather quickly, but that is why I bought this USB, so I don't have to deal with such degradation on my laptop's storage device (an eMMC). I have two ideas for how I can use this for swap space.

#### Scheme 1: One filesystem partition and many smaller swap partitions

The USB drive was advertised as having a capacity of 32 gigabytes, where a gigabyte is defined as `1000000000` bytes, but the actual available capacity discounting filesystem formatting is `307520000000` bytes (as an aside, there still is some false advertising going on here).

What I wish to do with this drive is to format it with a GUID partition table and create multiple partitions on it, with one partition being larger than the others and formatted with a basic filesystem (e.g., VFAT/FAT32, ext2, ext4). The total number of partitions will at least be in the hundreds and, discounting the larger filesystem partition, they will be of uniform size and will be used for paging/swapping space. The filesystem partition will be used to store data for managing this particular scheme.

The reason for using many small partitions here instead of a single partition or a swap file on a filesystem is to keep bad blocks from being scattered across the USB drive; this will make degradation easier to manage as any partitions containing bad blocks will no longer be used. Records about which partitions are unusable will be kept in the filesystem that will be on the single larger partition.

Device mapper's linear target will be used to create a single large device out of any number of the small partitions on the USB. The determination of which partitions to use to create the mapped device will be made from the data recorded in the filesystem partition. If I opt for an encrypted swap device, then I will store an encrypted key in the filesystem partition (or maybe on the host machine, instead).

Getting back to the matter of how I will partition the USB drive, the `30752000000` bytes of raw storage space translates to `60062500` sectors that are each `512` bytes in size. Using a GPT scheme means that there will be two regions, one at either end of the drive's storage space, that will not be available for use as part of a filesystem or for swap space. Given the practice of aligning partitions to `N`-sector boundaries, these two regions will be larger than the size of the partition table that I will use (the number of partition entries a GPT contains is adjustable and maxes out at `4294967295`).

Tools like `fdisk` and `gdisk` default to `2048`-sector alignment boundaries, which seems to suggest that 2048 is recommended or is in someway optimal. If I align my partitioning boundaries to `2048` sectors, then that leaves one `2048`-sector segment containing the primary GPT at the start of the drive, one partial 804-sector segment containing the backup GPT at the end of the drive, and `29326` `2048`-sector segments available for filesystem/swap partitions in-between them.

Keeping with a partition alignment to `2048`-sector boundaries, if the filesystem partition is `X` number of segments in size, then the total number of sectors left for use as multiple swap partitions,
 `Y`, is equal to `29326-X`. Now, since I want the swap partitions to be equal in size, the value of `Y` must be a composite number, and since a greater number of partitions could result in the partition table exceeding `2046` sectors in size, the number of swap partitions must be one of the larger factors of `Y`.

Generalizing the above, I get this math:

- `30752000000` is the size of the USB drive in bytes.
- `60062500` is the size of the USB drive in `512`-byte sectors.
- `p` is the number of partitions I will use.
- `P` is the size of the partition table in number of entries. This value is part of the GPT header.
- `q` is the size of the primary GPT in `512`-byte sectors. This value is equal to `ceiling(P/4)+2`.
- `r` is the size of the backup GPT in `512`-byte sectors. This value is equal to `ceiling(P/4)+1`.
- `N` is the number of sectors that partitions are aligned to.
- `Q` is the number of `512`-byte sectors at the beginning of the drive that cannot be a part of any partition. This value is equal to `N`.
- `R` is the number of `512`-byte sectors at the end of the drive that cannot be a part of any partition. This value is equal to `60062500 mod N`.
- `X` is the number of `N`-sector segments that are usable for partitions.
- `Y` is the size of the filesystem partition in `N`-sector segments.
- `Z` is the number of `N`-sector segments available for use as parts of  swap partitions. This value is equal to `X-Y`.
- `S` is the number of swap partitions I will use.
- `Z` must be divisible by `S`.
- `p` cannot exceed `P`.
- `r` cannot exceed `N`.

My questions for this scheme are:
+ Does partition alignment matter?
+ If it does, then should I align my partitions to boundaries of `2048` sectors or should it be some other number?
+ Is there a number I can pick for `N` that would evenly divide `60062500`. If there is, does it lead to any data overlap? If it's a number that isn't a power of two, then would it be a non-optimal choice?

#### Scheme 2: One filesystem partition and one larger LVM2 PV partitions

This idea is a lot like the the first one, but the difference is that the many smaller swap partitions would be replaced by a big partition formatted for use as a physical volume with LVM2. The large partition would be segmented into many logical volumes which could be resized and recombined as needed. The filesystem would serve a similar purpose as in the first scheme.

I see a few possible problems with this one:
+ I do not know if LVM2 works like a filesystem and if it moves the data comprising logical volumes around like the data that comprises files in a filesystem. If it does, then this would be problematic for isolating bad blocks, something which is a requirement for this scheme as it is in the first one.
+ I do not know if resizing and combining logical volumes would suffer from a similar problem as hypothesized in the preceding bullet point.
+ This one could be needlessly more complicated than the first idea, but I'm unable to say if it is or is not.

#### In conclusion…

Which scheme should I use? What are the answers to the questions/problems posed under each? Is there anyway I could utilize encryption for the swap space and would it (the encryption) be easy to get rid of when I don't need it? Would compressed swap memory like `zram` reduce the number of degraded blocks? If so, how do I use it? How do I determine the underlying block size of my USB drive? `hdparm` doesn't seem to help with that.

Comment: The best way to avoid wearing your swap drive is to have enough RAM and a low "swappiness". Putting your swap drive on a comparatively slow USB link doesn't look like a good solution. SSD devices have backup sectors that are transparently remapped to replace sectors going bad. When you start seeing bad sectors this means that the backups sectors are exhausted and thing go bad pretty quickly at that point and you should replace the device. OTOH recent devices wear out pretty slowly.

Comment: @xenoid I understand that having more RAM will alleviate the problem, but that was not part of the question. My RAM cannot be expanded.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't wanto to deal with degradation on my laptop's storage device (an eMMC)

The best way to do that is to install enough RAM and disable swap completely.

> The total number of partitions will at least be in the hundreds [...] The reason for using many small partitions here instead of a single partition or a swap file on a filesystem is to keep bad blocks from being scattered across the USB drive; this will make degradation easier to manage as any partitions containing bad blocks will no longer be used.

This makes no sense: It doesn't matter where the block is, all blocks can be accessed equally fast (or slow). The microcontroller in the USB stick will reassign bad blocks anyway, or use wear levelling and move around blocks in whatever way it pleases.

So, don't make lots of small partitions. Make one partition that's large enough for your projected memory use (how many and what programs do you use in the worst case?).

Using lvm just adds one level of indirection which will make everything slower.

To repeat: **The best thing is to install enough RAM, and disable swap completely.**

**Edit**: Explanation of *wear levelling*

The microcontroller of the USB stick implements a layer between the real (physical) blocks of the stick and the (logical) blocks that are accessible via USB.

Say, for illustration purposes, the stick claims to be some standard size, say 150 logical blocks. Some blocks always turn out to be bad after manufacturing and are flagged in the production process. Say the stick was produced with 200 blocks, of which 20 are bad. That's still ok, now you have 180 *physical* blocks, and that's more than the 150 *logical* blocks the stick claims to have.

Internally, the stick keeps track of a mapping between logical and physical blocks. Now say you make a partition from (logical) block 0 to 49, and write each block in this partition twice. The first time the stick will write physical blocks 0 to 49, and the second time it will write physical blocks 50 to 99. And so on.

So no matter what contrived partition scheme you come up with, you can't "save" good blocks for "later". That would also be a bad idea, because blocks become defective when transistors become leaky, and everything is packed very tightly. So a bad block can also affect neighbouring blocks and make them bad, and once the stick has a significant number of bad blocks I wouldn't trust it with important data, anyway.

Solutions in order of preference:

1) Turn off swapping completely, only use available RAM. Load times from USB swap will be similar to load times from internal flash storage, anyway. So close those applications you don't use, restart them if you need them again.

2) If you absolutely have to use more applications than will fit in your RAM, or if you want to hibernate, make a single partition of reasonable size (that will keep the OS tables to reasonable size), and leave the rest of the stick empty.

Set swappiness to "as low as possible". This will use all phyiscal blocks on your stick, and when it goes bad in a few years, throw it away and buy a new one. Don't try to store important data on it, use a different stick for that.

Comment: `The best way to do that is to install enough RAM and disable swap completely.` It is a Chromebook, so not possible. Please address the questions instead of suggesting this alternative.

Comment: `This makes no sense: It doesn't matter where the block is, all blocks can be accessed equally fast (or slow). The microcontroller in the USB stick will reassign bad blocks anyway, or use wear levelling and move around blocks in whatever way it pleases.` So, if I format the whole thing as a swap partition, use it for a while, then reduce it in size, and then format a filesystem on the remaining space, the filesystem won't be adversely affected?

Comment: (1) If you can't install RAM, see if the available RAM is already enough, then disable swap. And you didn't mention what kind of device it was. (2) Sticks use wear levelling, so on average, every block will be written the same number of times, no matter if it's in a swap partition or a file system. You can't work around that, because you can't override the stick microcontroller. So the FS *will* be affected (some blocks will already have been written a few times), but it will be affected no matter what you do.

Comment: (1) It's not enough RAM. (2) What do you mean the filesystem will be affected? If I only use the swap partition(s) and don't touch the filesystem partition, then why would the USB controller even touch the filesystem? If what you say is true, then we should expect untouched filesystem partitions to become modified by the USB's firmware.

Comment: Swap is an option if 1) it is very lightly used (mostly to avoid out of memory errors) or 2) it is on a device with very fast I/O. Having the system permanently swapping things to a USB device won't work.

Comment: *What do you mean the filesystem will be affected?* Because the firmware of the device doesn't see your partitioning. For it all sectors are equal, and it maps real sectors to virtual sectors which are the only thing your OS sees. So your OS partitions the virtual sectors, and they can be remapped transparently.

Comment: What are `OS tables`?

Comment: Mapping from internal RAM address to swap address, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late answer, but what i did in the case not possible to add more RAM is to use [ZRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zram).
I did these steps:

```
#to activate zram module:
modprobe zram 
#Assign 512Mb to the zram virtual space:
zramctl --size 512M /dev/zram0
#Now, make the zram device as a swap device:
mkswap /dev/zram0
#Enable swap memory
swapon /dev/zram0
```

Recommended to set swappiness as low as possible; only use it when the ram is fully (or very close to). That is the command to do so:

```
sysctl vm.swappiness=1
```

Now test that the changes are applied succesfully:

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

Should return *1*
Note: it will reset all the changes across reboots. to make it permanently [see this post](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Zram#Permanent_setup) from proxmox. This is from where i took the info and applied to my server.